# Exception when running Opencl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, opencl

I have downloaded, installed and linked OpenCL to a new project in Visual Studio 2012. I can include "CL/cl.h" with no problems. Everything compiles fine. But the first use of any OpenCL function throws this error:

```
 "Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000".
```

I have tried many examples and fixes but none seem so solve the problem.

I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2012's C++ compiler.

OpenCL is in AMD_APP_SDK/2.9

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit. Running Visual Studio as administrator.

My GPU is AMD Radeon HD 6770M. I can't think of anything else to do.

Thanks,
Will

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Maybe some buffer lengths mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem - solved by linking against 32-bit Opencl.lib (project target machine type was 32-bit)